# Retrieving the minimum element in a stack at a constant time

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack, min

Can you please help me understand what is going on in this line of code?

```
def push(self, x):
    self.stack.append(x)
    if len(self.minStack):
        if x < self.minStack[-1][0]:
            self.minStack.append([x, 1])
        elif x == self.minStack[-1][0]:
            self.minStack[-1][1] += 1
    else:
        self.minStack.append([x, 1])
```

it is taken from the line of this code:

```
class MinStack2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack, self.minStack = [], []

    # @param x, an integer
    # @return an integer

    def push(self, x):
        self.stack.append(x)
        if len(self.minStack):
            if x < self.minStack[-1][0]:
                self.minStack.append([x, 1])
            elif x == self.minStack[-1][0]:
                self.minStack[-1][1] += 1
        else:
            self.minStack.append([x, 1])
```

You can also find it at this GitHub account: https://github.com/kamyu104/LeetCode/blob/master/Python/min-stack.py

Thank you in advance

**Please, dont just mark it down if there is any misunderstanding for you. Leave a feedback rather. This is a plattform to learn and I feel like marking post down without an explanantion is very uneducated**

Comment: [How to debug small programs (#2)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - Use the code, pepper it with output statements and feed it demodata - until you understand it. Hint : there are 2 lists(aka stacks) one takes all elements in order, the other one holds lists inside of it with "Elements that were pushed and were minimal at the time" and a counter of how many were pushed - just printing `self.stack` and `self.minStack` at the start/end of `push(..)` and feeding it `[2,2,3,4,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,0]` a piece a time should give you an idea what it does.

Comment: This platform has rules about what you can learn - it is not a "tutorial" platform or "explain me code" forum - so your question is out of scope of the topics. To get the specifics, read  [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - sometimes questions get answered, sometimes downvoted and flagged for closing - no biggy if either happens - its not against _you_ its just a feedback on how the forumusers see your qeustions and if it fits in.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I am glad you left a feedback and didnt marked the post down. I am definitely aware that mark down a post isnt opposed to **me** . Besides, I heard of  **stack overflow** as a platform to ask questions. My question was certainly not indeed for a tutorial but a simply answer and clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you `push` onto the stack, you also check if this item is smaller than the previous minimum, which is kept on top of `minStack`, along with the count of how many of that item are in the stack.

If the item is smaller, then you push it (with a count of 1) onto `minStack`.  If it's the same, you increment the count of that item by one.

Every time you pop an item, if it is the smallest item in the stack (i.e. `== minStack[-1][0]`), you decrement the count of the smallest item.  If that count becomes zero, you pop the item off `minStack`.  Now the smallest item in the stack is whatever it was before the first of that smaller item was added.  This is because in order to discard that first instance of the smallest item, we had to pop everything on top of it first, essentially rolling the stack back to the point in time at which the smallest element was added.

PS: When you find yourself writing your own stack implementations, know that any stack that doesn't return the items it `pop`s is acting very strangely.